# Footer and header within a div

Tags: html, css

On my page I have the following html structure:

```
<body>
   <div id="container1">
      <div id="container2">
         <div id="container3">
            <div id="body">some body content</div>
            <div id="footer">footer content</div>
         </div>
      </div>   
   </div>
</body>
```

The structure cannot change. I need the footer div of fixed height to be always at the bottom of the page. If the body content expands and is higher than browser window the footer needs to be shifted as well, so it's always below the body content.

I need something exactly like in the solution described in the link, but adjusted to my html structure: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page

I tried following CSS from the link, but it doesn't work for long body content - the body text goes underneath the footer (footer should be shifted instead):

```
html,
body {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   height:100%;
}
#container {
   min-height:100%;
   position:relative;
}
#body {
   padding:10px;
   padding-bottom:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
}
#footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
   background:#6cf;
}
```

The solution needs to work on IE8.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is here... do you have a specific problem?

Comment: I have troubles achieving the described layout. Tried applying the css from the linked post, but it doesn't seem to work with my html structure

Comment: That will keep the footer below body content #footer{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
} Please see this fiddle, is this what you want?http://jsfiddle.net/hmLjc7b3/

Comment: Change your div to html5 footer element. use css3 calc() to measure heights. i.e footer{height:calc(100%-200px);}

Comment: Harry - the footer should be at the bottom of the page if body has little content, your fiddle doesn't do that

Comment: Billy - it needs to run on IE8 so I don't think HTML calc is an option here

Answer (score 2):

You need min-height:100% on all of your parent containers, because container 3 always needs to be at least full height of the viewport (browser height).

like this:

```css
html,
body {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   height:100%;
}
#container1 {
  min-height:100%;
}
#container2 {
  min-height:100%;
}
#container3 {
   min-height:100%;
}
#header {
   background:#ff0;
   padding:10px;
}
#body {
   padding:10px;
   padding-bottom:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
}
#footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
   background:#6cf;
}
```

```html
<div id="container1">
   <div id="container2">
      <div id="container3">
        <div id="body">some body content</div>
        <div id="footer">footer content</div>
      </div>
   </div>   
</div>
```

Comment: If you add enough content to this layout, then the content in `#body` will flow under the `#footer`, so this approach does not do what the OP needs.

Comment: I confirm - this doesn't work as described

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you might be able to do it without using the CSS `calc` function (not supported by 
IE8).

The solution depends on CSS tables, which are supported by IE8.

The trick is to apply `display: table` to the wrapping container elements with `height: 100%`.
Tables treat height values as minimum values to the tables will be at least 100% of the height and
then expand based on the content.

Applying `display: table-row` to the footer causes the browser to treat `#body` like a table-cell
and the height will fill up the height of the containing block not used by the footer.

You may need to wrap your footer content in another block element depending on the details of 
your layout.

**Note:** Test in IE8 first... interesting proof-of-concept at the very least.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.setMinHeight {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
}
#body {
  overflow: visible;
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
} 
#footer {
  display: table-row;
  height: 60px;
  background: tan;
}
```

```html
<div id="container1" class="setMinHeight">
  <div id="container2" class="setMinHeight">
    <div id="container3" class="setMinHeight">
      <div id="body">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent ac tortor cursus, tempor nibh sed, elementum eros. Mauris condimentum magna non posuere commodo. Nunc a lorem at purus molestie placerat ut a mi. Etiam a dui lacus. Etiam pretium
          quam arcu, et tristique ipsum pulvinar non. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Maecenas ante eros, accumsan sollicitudin tellus a, tempus mattis ante. </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent ac tortor cursus, tempor nibh sed, elementum eros. Mauris condimentum magna non posuere commodo. Nunc a lorem at purus molestie placerat ut a mi. Etiam a dui lacus. Etiam pretium
          quam arcu, et tristique ipsum pulvinar non. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Maecenas ante eros, accumsan sollicitudin tellus a, tempus mattis ante. </p>
      </div>
      <div id="footer">footer content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: doesnt work with IE8 document mode emulation